# Regex match on string only, not substrings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm adding strings to a textarea when values in a table are clicked. It has to be possible to select and deselect values in the table, and they will add/remove themselves from the textarea. The textarea has to be a string, and the added values can't be wrapped in any other characters.

The values that are being added could potentailly have any characters in, and may have one of the other of the values as a substring, here are some examples: `HOLE 1`, `HOLE 11`, `HOLE 17`, `HOLE (1)`, `cutaway`, `cut`, `away`, `cut-away`, `Commentator (SMITH, John)`, `(GOAL)`, `GOAL`

Once a value has been appended to the textarea, and it's clicked again to deselect it, I'm searching for the value and removing it like so:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?![ .,]|^)?(" + mySelectedText + ")(?=[., ]|$)", 'g');
var newDescriptionText = myTextAreaText.replace(regex, '');
```

The regex matches correctly for strings/substrings of text e.g. `cutaway` and `away` however wont work for anything beginning with a bracket e.g. `(GOAL)`. Adding the word boundary selector to the start of the expression `\b`, will make the regex match for strings that start with a bracket but wont work for strings/substrings containing the same text.

Is there a way to achieve this using regex? Or some other method?

Here's a working CodePen [example](http://codepen.io/JoeHastings/pen/BRavPM) of the adding/removing from table.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Why not keep the selected values in an `array` and refresh the contents of the `textarea` based on that when the values change?

Comment: I was thinking of that too but users can type in the box too e.g. "Look at `HOLE 1` now take a look at `HOLE 11` blah blah", but half way through typing they could click `HOLE 1` and remove it, although thinking about it again I could probably store an array of objects that contained the string itself and its current start position in the textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries (`\b`) to avoid issue when you deselect `away` and have `cutaway` in the list. Just change the regex to:

```
regex = new RegExp("(?![ .,]|^)?(\\b" + cellText + "\\b)(?=[., ]|$)", 'g');
                                 ^^^                ^^^
```

---

Here's the code I changed to make it works:

```
removeFromDescription = function(cell) {
        cell.classList.remove(activeClass);

        // Remove from the active cells arry
        var itemIndex = tempAnnotation.activeCells.indexOf(cell.textContent);
        tempAnnotation.activeCells.splice(itemIndex, 1);

        // Do the regex find/replace
        var annotationBoxText = annotation.value,
        cellText = regexEscape(cell.textContent), // Escape any funky characters from the string

        regex = new RegExp("(^| )" + cellText + "( |$)", 'g');

        var newDescription = annotationBoxText.replace(regex, ' ');

        setAnnotationBoxValue(newDescription);

        console.info('cellText:         ', cellText);
        console.info('annotationBoxText:', annotationBoxText);
        console.info('newDescription:   ', newDescription);
    };

    regexEscape = function(s) {
         return s.replace(/([-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])/g, `\\$&`);
    };

    setAnnotationBoxValue = function(newValue) {
        annotation.value = newValue;
    };
```

Comment: You right this does make that regex match on the substrings correctly, however if `cellText = (GOAL)` i.e. starts with a bracket this won't match